# loaderInfo.addEventListener does not work when called inside a function

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have preloader code in my main FLA, and I load the corresponding preloader (a small file) externally.  When I detect that the file is fully loaded, I need to add the listener to the content that I want to "preload".

```
function swfLoadedHandler(e:Event):void {
    preloader_movie = MovieClip(preloader_carregador.content);

    loaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, update);    
}
```

If I use it this way, the `loaderInfo` listener does not work, but if I add the listener ouside of the handler function, it does.
The problem is, I need it to work from within the complete handler, because obviously, the preloaded can show the % completed only after it's loaded...

Comment: Which loaderInfo are you adding the listener to?

Comment: From the system, like this.loaderInfo

Comment: Try this: add the listener outside of the function, like you used to.  Then trace the progress event's bytesTotal and bytesLoaded.  Also put a trace in the swfLoadedHandler.  That way, you'll see if your main movie is loaded before the external load completes.  I wouldn't be surprised.

Answer (score 1):

It is better if you show more code. But it seems that loaderInfo doesn't send PROGRESS event after file was loaded and as result update handler wasn't called.

[Here you see more about file loading](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html)